# Command line switches for CWBTF.EXE aka Data Transfer From IBM i..?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I would like to add an `Edit` action to the right-click context menu for IBM `*.DTF` files in my Windows Registry.

What are the command lines switches for `CWBTF.EXE`..? Is there a switch for "open DTF file for editing" (but do not run it)..?

I've searched Google, StackOverflow, and the [the IBM i 7.3 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahg/welcome.htm) for any mention of the command line switches for `CWBTF.EXE` aka "Data Transfer From IBM i", but I've found none.

The shortcut on my Windows Start Menu for "Data Transfer From IBM i" has the `/t` switch, but I cannot find any information on this.

I did find the command-line transfer utility `RTOPCB.EXE`, which does have some `/?` help text, but the options did not seem to relate much to the full-GUI version `CWBTF.EXE`.

Comment: I actually am having a bit of trouble understanding the question. By default, the CWBTF.EXE program does *not* run the transfer. It *does* provide a *button* that will run the transfer when clicked. So the "open" action *is* the "edit" action, as long as you don't click the button; unless you want some kind of raw editing of the text itself, in which case you wouldn't want CWBTF.EXE at all, but Notepad or the like.

Comment: Hmmm, yes now I understand my question could be confusing, and I didn't think of this particular bit when I posted it. You are of course correct: the default action is to open the DTF file. But what happens after that is dependent on the _settings in the file_. For instance, if the `Run automatically` option is enabled, that's what's going to happen, as will `Close on completion`. But what I'm looking for, and what I failed to properly ask in my question, is an `Open` action that overrides `Run automatically` if selected, and opens the DTF file without running it.

Comment: And now that I've laid all that out, I do understand this may not be possible, because a function to do such a thing may not be present in the `Data Transfer From IBM i` utility. It would require a command line switch to override the `Startup` options, and if there isn't such a thing, as the old saying goes, c'est la vie..!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the documentation on the old Client Access program (CWBTF.EXE) exists.  However, if you are able to use the newer Java based Access Client Solutions, the documentation for scripting can be found [here](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/as400/products/clientaccess/solutions/GettingStarted_en.html).  In particular, look for `/plugin=download` for transfer from IBM i.

Comment: Thank you. That's one of my middle- to back-burner projects. Not quite JAVA, but I want to take a stab at automating data transfers via COM objects in Access or Excel VBA. I have the IBM i Developer Tools installed, with the documentation for COM and .Net. That would solve all of my problems and I could do anything I need to. I might get into it after the new year and tax season blows over.

Comment: You don't need Java to do the scripting portion of this.  The `/plugin=download` is a command line option to run the proper utility.  Your question is a little vague about what you are trying to do but I can tell you I use this information to run my own transfer Powershell scripts.  The script edits the `.dtfx` file with the information I get from the script and then the script runs the transfer program using the `/plugin=download` or `/plugin=upload` respectively depending on what I want to do.

Comment: @Player1st - I started writing my answer before your comment showed up, but what you describe sounds exactly like what my answer is suggesting; just that you are working with `.dtfx` rather than `.dtf`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are command-line switches which will override the "run automatically" setting. It seems unlikely. But depending on how determined you are, and how comfortable you are with scripting, a workaround could be to write your own `CWBTF.EXE` wrapper in a scripting language of your choice.

In broad strokes, your *wrapper* would go ahead and modify the `.dtf` file (or a copy of it) to ensure `AutoRun=0` appears in the `[Properties]` section. Then it would call `CWBTF.EXE` on the modified `.dtf`. Then after that, if it's well-behaved, it would restore the `.dtf` to its original state (or remove the altered copy).

Armed with such a script, you could associate `Edit` with the wrapper.